# MySQL query to return associated data and not what is searched for

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get my head around the logic of a query I'm trying to write.

It's the equivalent of asking someone to go find a sock but only return what they found along with it, and not the sock itself.

Okay, so let's say booking 54,321 has three data objects; 123, 124, and 125. I run the query to see if data object 125 is the sock, and if so, return 123 sofa and 124 carpet, too. Or, more specifically, any data objects it can find. Presently, it's only returning what it finds, which is the sock.

I'll explain what's happening. Each booking can have any number of related data objects, or records. I'm using some of these records as flags, to mark a booking for special attention. So the sock I'm looking for is really a flag! But I don't want the flag, I want the other records that contain actual data.

I have other queries working, where I retrieve the booking and all related records, but just not in this context.

I'm using a table for the actual types of data being stored, establishing a relationship with the client:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings_clients_options` (
  `bookings_client_option_id` mediumint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modification_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `client_id` mediumint(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('text','textarea','checkbox','radio','select','multiselect') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
  `rules` text NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `note` text NOT NULL,
  `process` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `mode` enum('public','private','closed') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'public',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookings_client_option_id`),
  KEY `index` (`client_id`)
);
```

I'm using a table for the actual data itself, establishing a relationship with the booking:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings_clients_options_data` (
  `bookings_client_option_data_id` mediumint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modification_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `bookings_client_option_id` mediumint(11) NOT NULL,
  `booking_attendee_id` mediumint(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookings_client_option_data_id`),
  KEY `index` (`bookings_client_option_id`,`booking_attendee_id`)
);
```

Hopefully, that makes sense.

Any ideas what kind of query that might look like, in pseudo or actual code?

Comment: I might be wrong, but do not you need a booking_id also in bookings_clients_options table?

Comment: No, because they aren't specific to the booking. As I said, they're specific to the client, and from there, the "meta data" can then be assigned to any booking.

If I did what you suggested, I'd only ever be able to assign a client option to one booking.

It's a structure that's working perfectly in other parts of the system, but just not here, where I'm looking for a flag, but only to identify which records I need.

Comment: Put the query that you use to make it more obvious, please. It is not really clear what you are trying to achive here.

Comment: Being able to articulate the problem is part of the problem. But, in the end, I figured it out for myself.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I figured it out for myself. You'll see from the last four INNER JOIN parts that I had to alias the tables:

> SELECT
>
> bookings.booking_id,
>       DATE_FORMAT(bookings.creation_date, '%a %D %b %y') AS creation_date,
>       DATE_FORMAT(bookings.modification_date, '%a %D %b %y') AS modification_date,
>       bookings.client_id,
>
> bookings_attendees.name,
>       DATE_FORMAT(bookings_attendees.stay_date, '%a %D %b %y') AS stay_date,
>       bookings_attendees.stay_nights,
>
> venues.venue_id AS venue_id,
>       venues.name AS venue,
>       venues.town_city,
>
> DATE_FORMAT((
>
> SELECT
>               MAX(bookings_history.modification_date) AS booking_history
>           FROM bookings_history
>           WHERE
>               (bookings_history.booking_id = bookings.booking_id)
>
> ), '%a %D %b %y, %H:%i') AS booking_history,
>
> COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a2.value SEPARATOR 0x1D), 'NULL') AS clients_options FROM
>       bookings_attendees INNER JOIN
>       bookings ON
>       (bookings.booking_id = bookings_attendees.booking_id) AND
>       (bookings.client_id = '3') AND
>       (bookings.status = 'confirmed') AND
>       (bookings.mode = 'public') INNER JOIN 
>       bookings_clients ON
>       (bookings.booking_id = bookings_clients.booking_id) INNER JOIN
>       clients ON
>       (clients.client_id = bookings_clients.client_id) AND
>       (clients.client_id = '1') INNER JOIN
>       venues ON
>       (venues.venue_id = bookings.venue_id)
>
> **INNER JOIN
>       bookings_clients_options a1 ON
>       (a1.client_id = '3') INNER JOIN
>       bookings_clients_options_data a2 ON
>       (a1.bookings_client_option_id = a2.bookings_client_option_id) AND
>       (a2.booking_attendee_id = bookings_attendees.booking_attendee_id)**
>
> **INNER JOIN
>       bookings_clients_options b1 ON
>       (b1.client_id = '3') INNER JOIN
>       bookings_clients_options_data b2 ON
>       (b1.bookings_client_option_id = b2.bookings_client_option_id) AND
>       (b2.booking_attendee_id = bookings_attendees.booking_attendee_id) AND
>       (b2.bookings_client_option_id = '4') AND
>       (b2.value = 'Y')**
>
> GROUP BY bookings.booking_id ORDER BY bookings_attendees.stay_date